# Memory leakage in angular 2/4

Tags: angular, memory-leaks

How can i check if there is any **Memory Leakage** in my **Angular 2/4** Application? What is the best tool/way to check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Chrome DevTools**. To use it go to the **[Profiles panel](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/heap-snapshots)**, select the Record Allocation Timeline radio button and press the Start button. Now run the action that you suspect is causing the memory leak, and then press the stop recording button when you are finished.